# Signcolumn covers numbers in neovim

Tags: neovim

Ok, I can't get my Neovim to show both the relative numbers and signs with gitsigns plugin.

How to display both signs and numbers?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN5o6.png) of my neovim

Part of my init.vim with settings

```
" set number
set relativenumber
set wrap
set noswapfile
set encoding=utf-8
set hidden
set nowritebackup
set cmdheight=2
set updatetime=300
set shortmess+=c
set mouse=a " nv for normal and visual only
set cursorline
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
set splitright
set splitbelow
set signcolumn=yes
set numberwidth=5
```

Part with gitsigns

```lua
lua << EOF
  require("gitsigns").setup {
    signcolumn = true,
    current_line_blame = true,
    current_line_blame_opts = {
      virt_text = true,
      virt_text_pos = 'eol', -- 'eol' | 'overlay' | 'right_align'
      delay = 500,
    }
  }
EOF
```

And if it's important, I use Alacritty and added 5px padding for its window.

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem stated in the question?

Comment: @Usiel no, but when i moved my neovim config to lua, it worked

Comment: or maybe, it's just a coincidence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following configuration worked for me. In fact this problem is discussed in an [issue](https://github.com/lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim/issues/208) in the plugins repo, where I found the solution.

```
 require('gitsigns').setup{
    signcolumn = auto,
    on_attach = function()
    vim.wo.signcolumn = "yes"
    end
    }
```